# Skeleton responsive grid broken - columns dropping down

Tags: css, xhtml, skeleton-css-boilerplate

So, I've just began playing around with the demo of Skeleton, the responsive grid framework.

On my demo page, in the header I've tried to put the H1 in to an eight column div, and the buttons in to an eight column grid - these are inside a 16 column container.

However, the buttons drop below the H1.

I really can't see where this has gone wrong, if anyone can see something obvious then it would be most helpful.

Comment: You should post code rather than link to a webpage. The page may "go away" someday and leave nothing for future people to reference if they have a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a lo of code to post up (skeleton css is huge, and the HTML markup isn't exactly small). Any answer will be generic as the skeleton css is standardised it will still make sense. Makes the downvote rather silly.

Comment: All you would need to extract is the code relevant to your issue. Just looking in Firebug, you would have just a few elements to replicate the header code HTML and each of those elements appear to have 2-4 styling selectors associated with each to reproduce the layout (you don't need to post the entire skeleton css). A common misconception is that all the code must be there, when in fact often just a small portion can reproduce the issue in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and be posted within the question for reference.

Comment: @user319940 There was some problem with your site and then somehow you fixed it. Great, but what about the other user that will find your question later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the documentation is a bit unclear - alpha and omega need to be added to first/last columns to sort out the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has to do with the margins. The `width` of the `.sixteen.columns` (`940px`) does not seem to support the `width` and `margin` of two children that are `.eight` wide ([460px x 2] in width + [10px x 4] in margins = `960px`). I don't know enough about Skeleton to know if this is their issue or not, but it seems so.

You need to determine how you want those children to react. You can do one of two things easily, though how it affects your "column" alignment will vary.

**#1 Reduce All Child Margins**

```css
.sixteen > .eight.columns { 
    margin-right: 5px; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
}
```

**#2 Keep the Outer Margin and Eliminate Center Margin**

```css
.sixteen > .eight.columns:first-child { 
    margin-right: 0;  
}

.sixteen > .eight.columns:last-child { 
    margin-left: 0;  
}
```